# Update query not working in sqlite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using very simple code for updating a twofield value in a row but it is not updating the value. Here is my code:

```
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

public int updateContact(Biller_model_db contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_TYPE, contact.getType());
    values.put(KEY_AMOUNT, "Rs 0.0");
    values.put(KEY_DATE, "");

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " =?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}
```

Here I am trying to update amount and date.
This is how i am adding record

```
DatabaseHandler_Update db = new DatabaseHandler_Update(
                                                    SingleItemView.this);


                                            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                                            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                                    "yyyy/MM/dd");
                                            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();


                                            cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -Integer.parseInt(duedate));
                                            System.out.println("hellozzzzzzzzz"
                                                    + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
                                            db.addContact(new Biller_model_db(rank, country,
                                                    "Rs " + update_amount.getText().toString(),
                                                    "Due " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())));
```

Please correct if I am wrong somewhere. There is no error and code is not crashing but the values are not getting updated.

Comment: the id is probably wrong, then

Comment: where to put the id in this

Comment: Id is 1 by the way

Comment: You've already "put the id in this", he's saying that it may be incorrect in the table you want to update

Comment: Try using `null` for your selection arguments and rather set the ID in the selection string parameter: `return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = "+String.valueOf(contact.getID()),null);` - but the ID must exist in the database already for any updates to go through.

Comment: ya i added one record which i want to change. Replaced the code with yours but still no update

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla what would make you think it would work any better?

Comment: @njzk2 I just felt it made sense instead of having an array of one item - not necessarily a performance consideration. xyz, did you try with the hardcoded ID? Just to be sure you use an ID for which you already have a row in your database.

Comment: @xyz, post the code where you put the id in the contact object (whether it is from the database or otherwise)

Comment: Show the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
// Updating information based on table name and Condition

```
private int updateData(String tableName, ContentValues values, String condition) {
    try {
        openDataBase();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return myDataBase.update(tableName, values, condition, null);
}
```